# Unable to start mysql in ubuntu 18.04.02

Tags: 14.04, mysql

```
pc-050@pc050:~$ service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
pc-050@pc050:~$ systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-02-28 16:36:10 IST; 3s ago
   Process: 3826 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 28 16:36:10 pc050 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 28 16:36:10 pc050 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 28 16:36:10 pc050 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Feb 28 16:36:10 pc050 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 28 16:36:10 pc050 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 28 16:36:10 pc050 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
pc-050@pc050:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "feature" of systemctl. There is a parameter in the file that limits the restart frequency in seconds. Lower this while testing.

Try waiting (rather than editing the actual service file) to see if the problem resolves itself after some time has passed.

If this doesn't work, a reboot should resolve it `systemctl reboot`